# How can I connect to my home PC's or my Android's internet connection remotely from another phone?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to use the internet on my phone through my home computer (Windows) or another phone. How can I achieve this? Any step by step guide?

Comment: Google "tethering".

Comment: Does that work remotely? Remotely = one device in one country, the other device in another country.

Comment: No, the target device needs to be in wireless radio range of the source. <20 metres away is what you're aiming for.

Comment: or cable length. I can tether my phone over wifi or USB. In order to reach a device in another country, you'd already need some kind of internet connection, which makes the whole thing a bit pointless.

Comment: It is doable but not cheap. Hardware IPSec VPN router at home site. IPSec app for Android. Set up the connection and it should work. We did this on Android for accessing a Windows Server from overseas.